# ttyACM0 connected but not showing received data

Tags: usb, raspberry-pi, tty, serial-port, ttyusb

I have a STM32F4 microcontroller, with the USB interface, I connected it to the raspberry pi. When connected, it shows up as `/dev/ttyACM0`. I send some chars every second from the device.

In windows, with putty, all works fine. I receive the chars nicely.

On the raspberry pi, if I run the command:

```
>> sudo tail -f /dev/ttyACM0
```

It does not show anything on the screen. In my debugger, I do see that the device does not "hang", it seems like it is sending properly.

If the `tail` command is not running, the device (with a simple program) does hang, and the watchdog timer does time out.

This behavior seems normal, as I have the same symptom in windows when putty is not listing.

How to display the sent chars?

Is this a problem with rights? Should I use another program? I did try some suggestions from forums: change rules in `99-com.rules, set all rights to`/dev/ttyACM0`, but with no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PuTTY is a terminal emulator, and as such, is definitely designed to process individual characters at a time.

But `tail` on the other hand may be expecting complete lines of characters by default, either because of the design of the command, or because the TTY driver is buffering the output (unless its default settings are overridden).

You could either use a program that is more aware of the nature of the TTY driver and serial ports, like `minicom` or `cu`. If you find them working but unsuitable for your uses, perhaps use `stty -a -F /dev/ttyACM0` to list the TTY device settings when either of them is using the port, and then use the `stty` command to reproduce those settings before using `tail -f`. You'll probably need something like this to disable all the TTY device default features you won't need in this use case:

```
stty -F /dev/ttyACM0 -crtscts ignbrk -icrnl -onlcr -ixon -opost -isig -icanon -iexten -echo -echoe -echok -echoctl -echoke
```

Note: the `stty` option syntax is archaic, and the minus sign in front of each option keyword will *disable* the corresponding TTY device option; using the keyword without the minus sign would enable it.

If it turns out that the version of `tail` command you're using (probably from GNU `coreutils` package, but might also be from `busybox` depending on exactly what distribution you're running in the RasPi) is fully line-oriented and cannot be changed, then it may still be unsuitable for the job, unless the characters the microcontroller is sending include Unix-style line-feed characters every now and then. (If the microcontroller is sending CR instead of LF, then the TTY driver can fix it for you if you enable the `icrnl` option.)

Comment: With "tail": After a long time, it would spit out all of the received data at once. So, it's probably blocking, or waiting until receive buffer full. Sending CR nor LF could make it display the data at realtime. 
with minicom: (sudo minicom -D /dev/ttyACM0) all was displayed, no problem. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash
cat < /dev/ttyACM0 | awk 'BEGIN { FS = "," } {OFMT = "%2.5f"}\
/GPGGA/ { print "ID: ", $1, "Time: ", $2, "Lat: ", $3, "Lon: ", $5, "Höhe: ", $10}' > data
```

This script works on Raspberry Pi. The data is stored in the file "data".

Comment: I spent too much time with C and python codes. The latitude and longitudes and the other data from my GPS are just NOT updated. But the script I just gave you (see above) works perfectly well. You can plot the data (longitude, latitude and height) with 'gnuplot' or any other system.

Comment: (1) Your code re-assigns ``OFMT`` once for each line of input.  This is ‘‘mostly harmless’’, but is unnecessary and theoretically inefficient.  Why not put the ``OFMT`` assignment into the `BEGIN` block?  (2) You don’t need to use backslashes to get a multi-line string when you’re already using quotes.  (3) You seem to be making a lot of assumptions about the OP’s situation — specifically, that their device is sending GPS data following some sort of standard format(?) — and so this answer, which may be useful to you, might not help the OP at all.